# Java Multilevel Inheritance - Protected Instance Variable in Level 1 Class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have an question which comes under multilevel inheritance in Java. All Three Classes are in Same package

I have class A  :

```
public class A {
   protected int x;
}

public class B extends A {
   public void doSomething {
      // x is visible.agreed, as it is a direct subclass of A
   }  
}


public class C extends B {
   public void doSomething {
      // x is still visible, how come? I mean it is at the 2nd level 
     //  I am confused why?
   }  
}
```

does it like have any significance? or it is behavior which we have to take it by default?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be?

Comment: I was thinking that this kind can only be done till direct child, not child of child. I think I am confused. Is it the case that I am mixing C++ and Java?

Comment: I think it is time to spend some time on reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

variable/methods marked with `protected` modifier are visible to all the classes in the same pacakage and only to subclasses in different packages.
below are the example cases.

```
package a;
class A{
protected int x;
}
class B extends A{
//x can be accessed from this class
} 

class C extends B {
//x can be accessed from this class
}
class D{
//x can be accesed this class but you will have to create A's instance 
}

package B 
class One {
//cannot access x from this class
}
class Two extends A {
//can access x from this class
}
```

Comment: but for class D you can not access it directly, you will have to create an object of A B or C to access it correct?

Answer (score 5):

The access level modifiers in Java are:

- `public` - visible to all code
- `protected` - visible to all code in the same package and to subclasses regardless of package
- *nothing* (default) - visible to all code in the same package
- `private` - visible only to code in the same class (including nested classes)

See, for instance, the Java tutorial [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) or (for lots of technical details) [section 6.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6).

Answer (score 5):

Definition of the keyword

**Protected**

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

I suggest you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 4):

The Java `protected` keyword works its way down to *all* subclasses (and [members of the package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)). *If* there was a `protected` member in `Object`, any object could access it. By contrast, `private` is only visible to the local class (and inner classes), and `public` is accessible by all.

Have a look at [this glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/protectedscope.html), which shows in-depth how `protected` members and methods are inherited, and the [Java documentation on inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot restrict access to members in subclasses. This rule applies to methods (you can't override `public` method and make it `private`) but you can see analogy here. If the field is `protected`, it will be `protected` in every subclass, no matter how deep. Of course you can't override fields in Java, but just to give you an overview.

Comment: Member methods can be made more visible in subclasses.

Comment: @TedHopp: that's right, I said you cannot *restrict* (make them *less* visible). But thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

> The **protected** modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within **its own package** (as with package-private) and, **in addition, by a subclass of its class** in another package.

So if your class `C` shares the package with `A` and `B`, **its accessible**.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is transitive: if class B inherits from class A; 
and class C inherits from class B; then C is also a 
subclass / child class / descendant of class A.